Error al crear un super usuario en taiga
No puedo crear un súper usuario en taiga, puedo crear el contendor y lo puedo ejecutar de manera local pero al ejecutar este comado $ ./taiga-manage.sh createsuperuser, me manda este error:

exec docker compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose-inits.yml run --rm taiga-manage createsuperuser Container taiga-docker-taiga-db-1  Running
Superuser creation skipped due to not running in a TTY. You can run manage.py createsuperuser in your project to create one manually.

